# Pandas groupby: How do I use shifted values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataset that represents reoccurring events at different locations.

```
df = [Datetime location time event]
```

Each location can have 8-10 events that repeat. What I'm trying to do is build some information of how long it has been between two events. (they may not be the same event)

I am able to do this by splitting the df into sub-dfs and processing each location individually. But it would seem that groupby should be smarter that this. This is also assuming that I know all the locations which may vary file to file.

```
   df1 = df[(df['location'] == "Loc A")]  
   df1['delta'] = df1['time'] - df1['time'].shift(1)  

   df2 = df[(df['location'] == "Loc B")]  
   df2['delta'] = df2['time'] - df2['time'].shift(1)  
   ...

...
```

What I would like to do is groupBy based on location...

```
dfg = df.groupby(['location'])
```

Then for each grouped location
   Add a delta column
   Shift and subtract to get the delta time between events

Questions:
Does groupby maintain the order of events?
Would a for loop that runs over the DF be better? That doesn't seem very python like.
Also once you have a grouped df is there a way to transform it back to a general dataframe. I don't think I need to do this but thought it may be helpful in the future.

Thank you for any support you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html looks like it provides what you need.

```
groups = df.groupby('location').groups
```

or

```
for name, group in df.groupby('location')
    // do stuff here
```

Will split it into groups of rows with matching values in the location column.

Then you can sort the groups based on the time value and iterate through to create the deltas.

Comment: JohnB - Yes I know how to group-by based on the location. That it actually included as part of the question. But when you group by you end up with a group-by object which you can iterate over. for a specific group is there a way to apply a shift to it. Or do I need to iterate over it. Also once you have the groups there seems to be options to process the data but not add another column to the group. This is kind of where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that when you group-by and identify a column to act on the data is returned in a series which then a function can be applied to.

```
deltaTime = lambda x: (x - x.shift(1))  
df['delta'] = df.groupby('location')['time'].apply(deltaTime)
```

This groups by location and returns the time column for each group.
Each sub-series is then passed to the function deltaTime.